# SQL can't create table, errno 150

Tags: mysql, sql, database, errno

I'm slowly going crazy because I tied a knot with keys in a database and now when I want to create the database on an other server, it constantly gives back an error.

The error occurs at the table 'product'.
I'll just give the entire script:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `sql324208` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `sql324208` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `sql324208`.`adres`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sql324208`.`adres` (
  `straatnr` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `postcode` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `plaats` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `adresid` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`adresid`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 6
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `sql324208`.`bak`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sql324208`.`bak` (
  `baknr` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`baknr`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 6
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `sql324208`.`fabrikant`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sql324208`.`fabrikant` (
  `naam` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `contactpersoon` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `telefoonnr` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `internetadres` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `adresid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`naam`),
  INDEX `fk_fabrikant_adres1_idx` (`adresid` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_fabrikant_adres1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`adresid`)
    REFERENCES `sql324208`.`adres` (`adresid`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `sql324208`.`klantkorting`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sql324208`.`klantkorting` (
  `kortingsid` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `jaaromzet` DECIMAL(12,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `jaar` YEAR NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `kortingspercentage` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`kortingsid`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 6
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `sql324208`.`klant`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sql324208`.`klant` (
  `naam` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `klantid` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `adresid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `kortingid` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`klantid`),
  INDEX `fk_klant_adres1_idx` (`adresid` ASC),
  INDEX `k_kk_idx` (`kortingid` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_klant_adres1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`adresid`)
    REFERENCES `sql324208`.`adres` (`adresid`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `k_kk`
    FOREIGN KEY (`kortingid`)
    REFERENCES `sql324208`.`klantkorting` (`kortingsid`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 6;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `sql324208`.`medewerker`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sql324208`.`medewerker` (
  `medewerkerID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `naam` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `afdeling` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`medewerkerID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 6
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `sql324208`.`verkoop-order`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sql324208`.`verkoop-order` (
  `verkoop-orderid` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `klantid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `medewerkerID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`verkoop-orderid`),
  INDEX `fk_verkoop-order_klant1_idx` (`klantid` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_verkoop-order_medewerker1_idx` (`medewerkerID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_verkoop-order_klant1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`klantid`)
    REFERENCES `sql324208`.`klant` (`klantid`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_verkoop-order_medewerker1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`medewerkerID`)
    REFERENCES `sql324208`.`medewerker` (`medewerkerID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 6
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `sql324208`.`factuur`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sql324208`.`factuur` (
  `verkoop-orderid` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `factuur-status` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `verzend-datum` DATE NOT NULL,
  `betaal-datum` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `verzend-adresid` INT NOT NULL,
  `bestel-adresid` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`verkoop-orderid`, `verzend-datum`),
  INDEX `f_a_idx` (`verzend-adresid` ASC),
  INDEX `f_a2_idx` (`bestel-adresid` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_factuur_verkoop-order1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`verkoop-orderid`)
    REFERENCES `sql324208`.`verkoop-order` (`verkoop-orderid`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `f_a`
    FOREIGN KEY (`verzend-adresid`)
    REFERENCES `sql324208`.`adres` (`adresid`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `f_a2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`bestel-adresid`)
    REFERENCES `sql324208`.`adres` (`adresid`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 6;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `sql324208`.`gang`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sql324208`.`gang` (
  `gangid` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`gangid`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `sql324208`.`product`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sql324208`.`product` (
  `productnr` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `naam` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `bestelcode` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `verpakking` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `fabrikant_naam` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `hoeveelheid_in_voorraad` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`productnr`),
  INDEX `fk_product_fabrikant1_idx` (`fabrikant_naam` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_product_fabrikant1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`fabrikant_naam`)
    REFERENCES `sql324208`.`fabrikant` (`naam`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 6;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `sql324208`.`inkoop-order_producten`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sql324208`.`inkoop-order_producten` (
  `productnr` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `inkoop-ordernr` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `aantal` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`productnr`, `inkoop-ordernr`),
  INDEX `fk_product_has_inkoop-order_inkoop-order1_idx` (`inkoop-ordernr` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_product_has_inkoop-order_product1_idx` (`productnr` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `iop_p`
    FOREIGN KEY (`productnr`)
    REFERENCES `sql324208`.`product` (`productnr`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `sql324208`.`inkoop-order`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sql324208`.`inkoop-order` (
  `inkoop-ordernr` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `leverdatum` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `besteldatum` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `medewerkerID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`inkoop-ordernr`),
  INDEX `fk_inkoop-order_medewerker1_idx` (`medewerkerID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `io_iop`
    FOREIGN KEY (`inkoop-ordernr`)
    REFERENCES `sql324208`.`inkoop-order_producten` (`inkoop-ordernr`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_inkoop-order_medewerker1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`medewerkerID`)
    REFERENCES `sql324208`.`medewerker` (`medewerkerID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 6;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `sql324208`.`prijs`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sql324208`.`prijs` (
  `productnr` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `datum` DATE NOT NULL,
  `prijs` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`productnr`, `datum`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_prijs_product1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`productnr`)
    REFERENCES `sql324208`.`product` (`productnr`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `sql324208`.`product-locatie`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sql324208`.`product-locatie` (
  `schapnr` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `productnr` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `gangid` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`schapnr`),
  INDEX `fk_product-locatie_product1_idx` (`productnr` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_product-locatie_gang1_idx` (`gangid` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_product-locatie_gang1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`gangid`)
    REFERENCES `sql324208`.`gang` (`gangid`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_product-locatie_product1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`productnr`)
    REFERENCES `sql324208`.`product` (`productnr`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 6;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `sql324208`.`robot`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sql324208`.`robot` (
  `robotnr` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gangid` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  `status` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Status voorbeeld:\nverwerken order <verkoop-orderid>, XX%',
  PRIMARY KEY (`robotnr`),
  INDEX `gang_idx` (`gangid` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `gang`
    FOREIGN KEY (`gangid`)
    REFERENCES `sql324208`.`gang` (`gangid`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 6;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `sql324208`.`verkoop-order_robots`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sql324208`.`verkoop-order_robots` (
  `verkoop-orderid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `baknr` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `robotnr` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`verkoop-orderid`, `robotnr`),
  INDEX `fk_robot_has_verkoop-order_verkoop-order1_idx` (`verkoop-orderid` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_robot_has_verkoop-order_bak1_idx` (`baknr` ASC),
  INDEX `ro_r_idx` (`robotnr` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_robot_has_verkoop-order_bak1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`baknr`)
    REFERENCES `sql324208`.`bak` (`baknr`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_robot_has_verkoop-order_verkoop-order1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`verkoop-orderid`)
    REFERENCES `sql324208`.`verkoop-order` (`verkoop-orderid`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `ro_r`
    FOREIGN KEY (`robotnr`)
    REFERENCES `sql324208`.`robot` (`robotnr`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 6;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `sql324208`.`verkoop-order_producten`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sql324208`.`verkoop-order_producten` (
  `productnr` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `verkoop-orderid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `aantal` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`productnr`, `verkoop-orderid`),
  INDEX `fk_product_has_verkoop-order_verkoop-order1_idx` (`verkoop-orderid` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_product_has_verkoop-order_product1_idx` (`productnr` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `vo_pr`
    FOREIGN KEY (`productnr`)
    REFERENCES `sql324208`.`product` (`productnr`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `vo_vop`
    FOREIGN KEY (`verkoop-orderid`)
    REFERENCES `sql324208`.`verkoop-order` (`verkoop-orderid`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `sql324208`.`inkoop-prijs`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sql324208`.`inkoop-prijs` (
  `productnr` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `datum` DATE NOT NULL,
  `prijs` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`productnr`, `datum`),
  INDEX `fk_inkoop-prijs_product1_idx` (`productnr` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_inkoop-prijs_product1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`productnr`)
    REFERENCES `sql324208`.`product` (`productnr`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

The error is:

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `klheerde_db.product` ( `productnr` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `naam` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, `bestelcode` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL, `verpakking` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL, `fabrikant_naam` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, `hoeveelheid_in_voorraad` INT(11) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`productnr`), INDEX `fk_product_fabrikant1_idx` (`fabrikant_naam` ASC), CONSTRAINT `fk_product_fabrikant1` FOREIGN KEY (`fabrikant_naam`) REFERENCES `klheerde_db.fabrikant` (`naam`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 6
>   Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'klheerde_db.product' (errno: 150) 0.016 sec

Comment: Here's a bit of info on errno 105 that lists possible causes: [link](http://www.eliacom.com/mysql-gui-wp-errno-150.php)

Comment: @Ken What is the schema name - `klheerde_db`? There is such database in your script.

Comment: I read it, but all is equal. I checked that, I also tried it without AI, still no luck. I really am stuck...

Comment: well that's because I replaced the database name to put it on the new server

Comment: I have tryed the script. All tables are created.

Comment: really? that's strange, did you edit anything?

Comment: Did you rename a table? If you try to make it again (and so you're not dropping the old one) you'd have a named constraint allready there. Names should be unique, so, for instance, you can't create a second table with constraint 'fk_product_fabrikant1'

Comment: Nope, I did not rename a table...

Comment: I only renamed the scheme

Answer (score 1):

I tried to execute your DDL I had no error. So, I think that  the problem is that you are using a **CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS**. That implies if you have already the table created it wont update the structure. It is likely that the field **naam** doesn't exists in the table **fabrikant**.

You should try to drop your schema and start again from the beginning.

*Note: Your error code is equivalent to 1005. You can check your messages in the next link assuming you're using InnoDB.*

[14.2.11.1. InnoDB Error Codes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-error-codes.html)

Answer (score 0):

I this case the problem is different tables encoding. For solve this you need to add `DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8` part to all tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
  `productnr` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `naam` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `bestelcode` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `verpakking` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `fabrikant_naam` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `hoeveelheid_in_voorraad` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`productnr`),
  INDEX `fk_product_fabrikant1_idx` (`fabrikant_naam`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_product_fabrikant1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`fabrikant_naam`)
    REFERENCES `fabrikant` (`naam`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
AUTO_INCREMENT = 6;
```

Look [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=03d0462d615b91a455195f3e00502134&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80) for working solution